# React Native SectionList Images from JSON

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I'm having some trouble rendering an image onto a section list from a JSON file even though I am having no trouble with the text data.

here is my JSON DATA:

```
   {
      "title" : "Friday",
      "data": 
      [
         {
            "artist": "artist 1",
            "stage": "The Oak",
            "Instagram": "insta",
            "Spotify": "spot",
            "date": "10/8/2021",
            "Image": "../assets/art1.jpg",
            "Time" : "4:30PM - 5:00 PM"
         },
         {
            "artist": "artist 2",
            "stage": "The Oak",
            "Instagram": "insta",
            "Spotify": "spot",
            "date": "10/8/2021",
            "Image": "../assets/art2.jpg",
            "Time" : "5.00PM - 5:30 PM"

         }
         
      ]},
```

I am aware that you have to use the require function to render it but I just cant seem to get it right.

Here is the SectionList:

```
 <SectionList
      sections={data}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (<View style={styles.listItemView}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require(item.Image)} />

        <View>
          <Text style={styles.listItem}>{item.artist}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.listItemTime} >{item.Time}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>)}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{section.title}</Text>
        </View>)}
    />
```

Any help is welcome. Please let me know if I need to add addition info!

Thanks!

Comment: Dynamically importing is an anti pattern. You should not dynamically import images. Even if you successfully make it work, images still would not be copied to bundle because react native will think those images are not used. https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.22.1/docs/rules/no-dynamic-require.md

Comment: Thanks @UğurEren is there a way to achieve this effect correctly?

Comment: Without hardcoding each image in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a if-else or switch statement to get the image you want to use.

```js
const getArtImage = (artName) => {
  switch (artName){
    case 'art1':
      return require('../assets/art1.jpg');

    case 'art2':
      return require('../assets/art2.jpg');

    default:
      return require('../assets/defaultArt.jpg');
  }
}
```

and use this getArtImage function in your Image component.

```js
<Image style={styles.image} source={getArtImage(item.Image)} />
```

`item.Image` should be like `art1`, `art2` etc.

--

If your json is a local file, you can convert it to a js file.

```js
export default {
  title: "Friday",
  data: [
    {
      artist: "artist 1",
      stage: "The Oak",
      Instagram: "insta",
      Spotify: "spot",
      date: "10/8/2021",
      Image: require("../assets/art1.jpg"),
      Time: "4:30PM - 5:00 PM",
    },
    {
      artist: "artist 2",
      stage: "The Oak",
      Instagram: "insta",
      Spotify: "spot",
      date: "10/8/2021",
      Image: require("../assets/art2.jpg"),
      Time: "5.00PM - 5:30 PM",
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: thank you for sharing! Is a switch statement the best way to do this when there are over 50 images?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes